# How to dynamically load page into DIV in JSF with JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jsf, dynamic, load

In MVC3 I'd do something like this...

```
$('#myButton').click(function(){
  var route = '/Controller/Method?id=5';
  $('#myDiv').load(route);
});
```

Does anyone know how to do something like this in JSF?

Comment: Is this what you want? url: `var route = '<%=renderResponse.encodeURL(renderRequest.getContextPath()+ "/Controller/Method.jsp?id=5") %>'`

Comment: are you getting any errors in firebug ? is your url incomplete? what exactly the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Ajax jQuery method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and place the result in the div using the [appendTo method](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)
like this:

```
result.appendTo($('#myDiv'));
```